# SHA 256 Algorithm in Power Builder 6.5

Tags: algorithm, security, powerbuilder, hashalgorithm

I am trying to store the data as secured possible way in database.
  For that I am triyng to implement the SHA-256 algorithm in Powerbuilder version 6.5.
  This sound old that I am implememting the SHA 256 in PowerBuilder (Desktop Application Development Tool).
  Though yet it is outdated we need to implement this secure functionality in PowerBuilder
  Because lots of applications are dependant on it.

I Googled for any library for PB 6.5 for SHA256 but didn't get anything.
  So please can any one tell me how can I **achieve this SHA-256** in PowerBuilder or is there any ready library available fot SHA256 for PB 6.5.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: are you not able to include standard C/C++ libraries in powerbuilder? **libgcrypt** for example.

Comment: actually m a java developer but trying to implement SHA in PB as it is our customers req.so can you please tell me how to do that.And which are those libraries i can import.Thanks

Comment: Thanks all.Problem Resolved.I used this **capicom.dll** .This contain methods to generate HASH256 Algorithm

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [PB library](http://www.topwizprogramming.com/freecode_crypto.html) wich uses the Microsoft Crypto API.

The example is for PB 8+, I've managed to have it running in PB7 by exporting the nvo and windows objects and importing them in a new PB7 library.

According to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb931357%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you'll have to use the "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider" to be able to calculate the SHA256 hash.

Comment: Thanks all.Problem Resolved.I used this **capicom.dll** .This contain methods to generate HASH256 Algorithm.